Does SwiftUI View extension force redraw
I'm trying to understand how swiftUI view extensions work with this format:
func myExtension(newValue: Int) -> MyView {
        var view = self
        view.property = newValue
        return view
    }

Which are then used like this:
MyView()
    .myExtension(newValue: 2)

From what I understand, if View is a struct, and therefore is a value type, the line var view = self is creating a separate value, different from the original view. Therefore, by using this function on my view my original value is lost when it is created.
I see that this pattern is frequent, and that's why I find it strange that this is the way it works, is this forcing some view repainting or can it do it? Isn't it more optimal to pass directly newValue through the MyView init if I can do it?

It is best to pass via init, this is certainly creating a second "MyView"

Is view extensions really for setting properties, it doesn’t look right to me?

It doesn't look right to me either @JoakimDanielson, but I see this done in a lot of pages and tutorials, that's why I wanted some more info about this, which I'm struggling to find elsewhere.

Remember SwiftUI doesn’t draw or paint anything it's just view data that gets diffed and the framework generates the UI objects that do the drawing. The more View structs you have the more efficient the diffing so I would choose more structs over extensions.

var view = self is not "forcing some view repainting". This is simply because self is immutable, so we create a mutable copy so that we can change its properties.
SwiftUI only "repaints" a view (aka perform a view update) when one of that view's dependencies change. First, that view's body is called. Then return value of body is compared with the previous value of body (which SwiftUI stores somewhere). Finally, SwiftUI updates the UI according to the changes that it found.
So SwiftUI doesn't really care about what you do in body. Only the final view you create in body, when all the view modifiers and everything else have been evaluated, matters.
Importantly, the View structs you initialise in body are not what's on the screen (this is unlike UIViews from UIKit). body just returns a description of the views you want to show on screen (some may call this a "view model").
Because of this, SwiftUI Views are very lightweight - something like var view = self may seem like it is copying a whole view hierarchy, but that is not the case at all. The view hierarchy is computed in body, and var view = self obviously doesn't call body at all. Even if you do call body, this will not create the actual heavy-weight class instances that are on the screen - you are still just creating structs.

Isn't it more optimal to pass directly newValue through the MyView init?

I assume you are comparing MyView().myExtension(newValue: 2) and MyView(newValue: 2). There won't be much difference unless MyView is a very big struct, with lots of stored properties, which is time-consuming it to copy. However, you should not design MyView to be like that in the first place - you should split your views into small pieces. Furthermore, the compiler might be smart enough to optimise away the copy in the first place.
From a stylistic point of view though, it is more idiomatic to pass properties that are unique to that view through the view's initialiser. If the property is not unique to that view, you can consider passing it down the environment with a custom EnvironmentKey.
